# Why is 'position: relative' getting ignored for 'tr' elements on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

This issue started when I realized that the slide feature on my web application was not working on mobile, but was working on desktop. I have a table full of rows that each have an "x" next to them. When an "x" is clicked, I want the row to slide left and display a delete button. When it is clicked again, I want the row to slide back to its original position. I found I could do this by simply putting `overflow: hidden` on the `table` element and using `left` with a `transition` property on each `tr`. The following code works for me on desktop, but not for mobile:

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: left 0.5s;
}
.swipe {
    left: -70px;
}
```

HTML/PHP:

```
echo "
<div class='history'>
    <h2 id='weight-history-title' align='center'>Weight History</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class='th_border'>Date Weighed</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
";
while($row=$selectQuery->fetch_assoc()){
    $dateWeighed = htmlspecialchars(date("m/d/y", strtotime($row["date_weighed"])));
    $weight = htmlspecialchars($row["pounds"]);
    $id = htmlspecialchars($row["id"]);
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$dateWeighed</td>
            <td>$weight lbs</td>
            <td><img class='delete-icon' src='images/delete.png' style='cursor: pointer; width: 15px; height: 15px;'></td>
            <td class='delete'><a href='delete.php?id=$id' class='delete-button'>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
echo "
    </tbody>
</table>
";
```

JavaScript:

```
for(const x of document.querySelectorAll(".delete-icon")){
    x.addEventListener("click", function(){
        let tr = x.parentElement.parentElement;
        tr.classList.toggle("swipe");
        alert("tagname: " + tr.tagName + "\nclassname: " + tr.className + "\nposition: " +     getComputedStyle(tr).position);
    });
}
```

When an "x" is clicked, the class `swipe` is added to its parent row which should slide `70px` to the left, but on mobile, nothing happens when the "x" is clicked.

Through some research, I found out that the reason that it wasn't working on mobile was because `position: relative` was not getting applied to each `tr`. To double check this, I made JavaScript alert the `position` property of each `tr` when clicked. On desktop, it alerts `position: relative`, while on mobile it alerts `position: static`, which is default. I have tried adding `position: relative` using inline CSS on each `tr` and also using `!important` next to the property with no success.

Why would the `position` property be getting ignored on mobile?

NOTE: the code works when you preview a mobile screen through Developer Tools on desktop browser. You have to actually view the webpage on an IOS/Android device to see the issue. The table is at the bottom of the page.

Webpage URL: https://madlibsrandomgenerator.000webhostapp.com/weight/index.php

Comment: I'd like to help but the link you provided doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting an error? The link works for me.

Comment: It works now. I checked it on my Androud, the table works okay

Comment: It might be just iOS then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that `tr position: relative` is not supported in safari. That is why the code won't work on my mobile device.